# Cover report from Common Test when using rebar

Tags: erlang, rebar, test-coverage, common-test

I have an Erlang application that uses Rebar, and has tests written using Common Test.  I'd like to see the test coverage report for these tests, so I included the following line in my `rebar.config` file:

```
{cover_enabled, true}.
```

However, the "Coverage log" link in the Common Test report just leads to a page that says "Cover tool is not used". How can I get it to use the cover tool and give me a cover report when running the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cover_enabled` setting in `rebar.config` is necessary but not sufficient to activate cover reports for Common Test.  You also need to create a file called `cover.spec` in the root directory of your application, containing:

```
{incl_app, foo, details}.
```

(Substitute the name of your application for `foo`.)

That should give you a cover report for your application.